# Diode Power Dissipation

Tags: power, diodes, theory, formula-derivation, dissipation

I am having trouble solving this PD question. I feel like it’s straight forward but I can’t seem to get the correct answer. I was curious if I could get help from the community.

**Question**: A p-n diode have an on-voltage of 0.8 V at a forward bias current of 30 A and a leakage current of 3 mA at a reverse bias of 700 V. Calculate the average power dissipation in Watt at a duty cycle of 5%.

I’ve tried `0.8 V x 30 A x 0.05 = 1.2 W` which is incorrect. Then I tried getting the I_rms and utilizing that within the above equation and it's still wrong.

Any tips and tricks? Thank you in advance.

Comment: MrBlue, you don't need to generate RMS values for what appears to be a square-wave question. I think you are supposed to imagine that for 5% of the time the diode is forward biased with a 800 mV drop and 30 A current and that for the remaining 95% of the time the diode is reverse biased with 700 V and leaks at 3 mA during that part of the period. It's pretty easy to calculate the sum of the two dissipations for one whole period. Over an integer number of periods, as N approaches infinity, the average dissipation won't change from what it is for that one period. So that's all you need.

Comment: I'm sure @periblepsis is right, but it's a bit of a stretch to expect you to assume that the diode is reverse-biased during the other 95% of the duty cycle.  Normally, without explicit further information, the remainder of a duty cycle is assumed to be at  0V.  In an exam question you can probably assume that there's no extraneous information and that you need to use the reverse bias characteristics for something, but still I don't think the question is well-written

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we use the average integral:

$$
P_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\int_T P \ dt
$$

where \$P\$ is the power and \$T\$ is the period.

\$P\$ is the sum of on- and off-time dissipation. So,

$$
P_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\Bigg(\int_{T_{on}}V_F \ I_D \ dt+\int_{T_{off}}V_R \ I_R \ dt\Bigg)
$$

where \$T_{on}\$ and \$T_{off}\$ are on- and off-times, \$V_F\$ and \$I_D\$ are forward voltage and current, and \$V_R\$ and \$I_R\$ are reverse voltage and currents, respectively.

Since we are taking average, time units are not important i.e. they can be microseconds or kiloseconds. So we can use percentages directly:

$$
\begin{align}\\
P_{avg}&=\frac{1}{T}\Bigg(\int_{T_{on}}V_F \ I_D \ dt+\int_{T_{off}}V_R \ I_R \ dt\Bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{T}\Bigg(\int_0^{T_{on}}V_F \ I_D \ dt+\int_{T_{on}}^T V_R \ I_R \ dt\Bigg) \\
&=\frac{1}{100}\Bigg(\int_0^{5}V_F \ I_D \ dt+\int_{5}^{100}V_R \ I_R \ dt\Bigg) \\
&=\frac{1}{100}\Bigg(\int_0^{5}0.8 \cdot 30 \ dt+\int_{5}^{100} 700 \cdot 0.003 \ dt\Bigg) \\
&=\frac{1}{100}\Bigg(24 \cdot 5+2.1\cdot 95 \Bigg) \\
&=3.195 \text{W}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yeah. After seeing your comment all I did was type this into google search: .05*0.8 volt*30 amp+.95*700 volt*3e-3 amp.

Comment: This is great! I never thought of utilizing the off portion of the duty cycle. Which means sense. Thank you all!

Comment: @Mr.Blue if the answer is correct and satisfactory you can accept the answer by clicking the tick under the points counter, so that the question does not remain open.

Comment: @Mr.Blue The off portion is always important to consider too, especially when your diode is this leaky. Honestly, this diode is a pretty bad choice for this application; I suspect an SiC schottky would waste less power.